# unable to load msg: invalid name

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Using Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic and Python, I've created a msg in ~/catkin_ws/src/roboti_pi/msg: Num.msg with content:

int32[] data

My code to use this message:

a = Num()
a.data = [1, 2, 3]

This somehow gives an error for Num() so from ~/catkin_ws, I checked as shown at http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv with "rosmsg show src/roboti_pi/msg/Num and the result is

unable to load msg [src/roboti_pi/msg/Num]: invalid name [src/roboti_pi/msg/Num]

But what's invalid about it?

Thanks,

hvn

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251485/unable-to-load-msg:-invalid-name/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2017-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be `rosmsg show robot_pi/Num`

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2017-01-08**:
Thank you! This works.